# Code in <text> not executed anymore

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I had the existing codes that were working fine before jquery 1.10.2.  I have tried to run in debug mode, and it seems that the codes in the `<text>` are not being reached. CalculteMyAgeOne is reached, whereas CalculateMyAgeTwo is never reached.  I have the following codes in the View.  Why does it not execute the codes in the `<text>` anymore?

Note:
I have added AddRows function and the AddRows function is reached in debug mode however, it is not the case for CalculateMyAgeTwo

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        CalculateMyAgeOne();
@if (Mode)
{    
        <text>
            CalculateMyAgeTwo();
            AddRows(@(5 - Model.Rows.Length));      
        </text>
 }
    });

    function CalculateMyAgeOne() {
        $("#table tbody tr:last").hide();
    }

    @if (Mode){ //Note that Mode is true
    <text>
        function CalculateMyAgeTwo() {
        }
        function AddRows(rowsToAdd){
        }

    </text>
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "anymore"? I can't believe that it ever worked. You can only have JavaScript in `<script></script>` tags. Everything else like HTML is a syntax error.

Comment: @freakish definitely :)

Comment: I am surprised this worked previously to begin with. Other than that since you tagged mvc it may also be a feature where asp escapes your code to make it work/stop working

Comment: @AndreasMüller That's an interesting idea. However asp would have to parse everything and then realize that it is dealing with syntax error and then automatically alter/fix it? That would be a serious problem for developers (they wouldn't even know that they've made an error).

Comment: ultimately this leads to the question - why would you even write your code like that? if that actually ever worked and now stopped working it must be because a bug was fixed which made it work in the first place

Comment: I also find it hard to believe it ever had worked.. Why use the <text>-element there anyway? What was the original idea behind it when you put the tags there?

Comment: Yeah. Actually those `<text>` tags inside JS don't make any sense. Idea of escaping this by ASP is interesting. However if you think about it then it doesn't make any sense as well. What should ASP do with these tags anyway? If one developed a template language which clearly clashes with HTML syntax then this language should not be used.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo I agree. Also technologies which conflict with the way how web applications should work, should not be used either (webforms, cough)

Comment: you had <text> to test razor syntax ?

Comment: @NicoD: Yes it was used for razor syntax

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo Reminds me... I forgot - <text> is indeed part of the razor syntax. Convenient way to start/stop non-code blocks. See http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax

Comment: Ok. Kind of question with missing information. Still it stinks because of conflict with HTML syntax. Will never use anything like this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have tagged ASP MVC, I would like to clarify that the `<text>` element is a special Razor element (Razor being an ASP MVC view engine with its own syntax), that has nothing to do with JavaScript or HTML. From [this excellent post](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-razor-s-and-lt-text-gt-syntax) introducing some bits of the Razor syntax in ASP MVC:

> The  tag is an element that is treated specially by Razor. It
>   causes Razor to interpret the inner contents of the  block as
>   content, and to not render the containing  tag element (meaning
>   only the inner contents of the  element will be rendered – the
>   tag itself will not).  This makes it convenient when you want to
>   render multi-line content blocks that are not wrapped by an HTML
>   element.

For it to work,the `<text>` element has to be inside a Razor code block. Otherwise it will be rendered as is on the resulting HTML (in your case causing a syntax error).

**Assuming this script element is inside a Razor view,** the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        CalculateMyAgeOne();
        <text>
            CalculateMyAgeTwo();        
        </text>
    });
    function CalculateMyAgeOne() {
        alert("CalculateMyAgeOne");
    }
    function CalculateMyAgeTwo() {
        alert("CalculateMyAgeTwo");
    }
</script>
```

will be rendered exactly as it is on the HTML sent to the browser, and you would get a syntax error as the others have already pointed out. (Basically none of the alerts would be seen).

However if you have the `<text>` element inside a code block in your Razor view, as in this sample:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        CalculateMyAgeOne();
        @if ( true /* some meaningful condition in real code */ ) { 
            <text>
            CalculateMyAgeTwo();        
            </text>
        }
    });
    function CalculateMyAgeOne() {
        alert("CalculateMyAgeOne");
    }
    function CalculateMyAgeTwo() {
        alert("CalculateMyAgeTwo");
    }
</script>
```

Then this will render this resulting HTML when the condition is true:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        CalculateMyAgeOne();
            CalculateMyAgeTwo();
    });
    function CalculateMyAgeOne() {
        alert("CalculateMyAgeOne");
    }
    function CalculateMyAgeTwo() {
        alert("CalculateMyAgeTwo");
    }
</script>
```

If the condition were false, then the call to `CalculateMyAgeTwo` would not have been rendered. If you remove the `<text>` element in this last example, Razor would think `CalculateMyAgeTwo` is part of the server side C# code and you would get a server side error rendering the view.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Even CalculateMyAgeOne();
        @if ( true /* some meaningful condition in real code */ ) { 
            <text>
            CalculateMyAgeTwo();        
            </text>
        } does not reach the function CalculateMyAgeTwo(); .  Please note that I am using MVC5 and jquery 1.10.2

Comment: Is that included in a **.cshtml** file? The last example above should work and you should see 2 alerts. For example start a new MVC application and append it to your `_Layout.cshtml` file, right before the closing `</body>` tag.

Comment: Well it was working before I upgraded to Jquery 1.10.2

Comment: I have noticed your last update, don't you have to surround your first `<text>` block with the same conditional `@if (Mode){ ... }` ? Even if it worked as you claim, in the case were  Mode is false, the JavaScript code would be calling functions that doesn't exist in the HTML. (I still don't see how the standalone <text> element worked for you before, do you have access to the previous version of the code as in Git/TFS history?)

Comment: Yes, it should be surrounded.  Despite having both <text> blocks with the same conditional and Mode being true, the functions are not reached

Comment: Have you tried the example with the alerts? Do you see them? When you say they are not reached, what do you exactly mean? (Because if you mean a Visual Studio breakpoint, that is JavaScript code that will be run on the browser. You could use the browser developer tool, adding `debugger;` or `console.log` statements in your JS code)

Answer (score 2):

This is a syntax error in javascript. You can't have HTML elements (like `<text>`) inside JS code.
This will basically never work. Remove `<text>` tags and your JS will work again.

Answer (score 0):

The text tag needs a razor context or condition which was missing in your sample.

With Mode = true, the following updated sample is OK and  the functions are reached

```
@{
    var Mode = true;
}

<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        CalculateMyAgeOne();
        @if (Mode)
        {
            <text>
            CalculateMyAgeTwo();
            </text>
        }

    });

    @if (Mode)
    {
         <text>
        function CalculateMyAgeOne() {
            alert("one");
        }

        function CalculateMyAgeTwo() {
            alert("two");
        }
        </text>
    }

</script>
```